# Powershell import-module webadministration

Tags: iis, web-server, powershell

Every time I execute this command

```
invoke-command -computername REMOTEPC -scriptblock { import-module WebAdministration; new-item "$env:systemdrive\inetpub\testsite" -type directory; New-WebSite -Name TestSite -Port 81 -PhysicalPath "$env:systemdrive\inetpub\testsite" }
```

I get the following error

```
Invalid class string (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401F3 (CO_E_CLASSSTRING))
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

The website is created successfully as far as I can see.

The following command gives the same error when enumerating the testsite

```
Invoke-Command -computername REMOTEPC { import-module webadministration; dir -path IIS:\Sites\ }

Name             ID   State     Physical Path     Bindings      PSComputerName
Default Web Site 1    Started                     http *:80:    REMOTEPC

Invalid class string (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401F3 (CO_E_CLASSSTRING))
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCo
   mmand
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: @David: does the computer you are running the command on have the webadministration module installed and imported?

Comment: @MattB: You do not have to have the module loaded locally.  As per the ScriptBlock parameter details it, this will be run on the remote computer.

Comment: @Marco Shaw: where I was going with that is - I'm wondering if the remote call is passing back a property with a type from the webadministration module that the calling machine can't parse properly, but since he isn't using that property it doesn't affect his output. (I haven't been able to test this theory yet...)

Answer (score 4):

This is a serialization problem. `New-WebSite` and top-level WebSite information from the `IIS:\Sites\{sitename}` protocol both return objects of type `Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.Configuration`. That object contains a property `ftpServer`; and `ftpServer` isn't serializable.

`New-WebApplication` and Sub-WebApplication information from the `IIS:\Sites\{siteName}\{subappname}` protocol do not have an `ftpServer` property. They won't have the same serialization error.

@cad's solution is great, because it prevents the remote script from returning any objects.

But, if you want to return the website information from the remote machine, you can use:

```
$scriptBlock = {
    Import-Module WebAdministration

    $site = Get-Item IIS:\Sites\www.sitename.com

    $site.ftpServer = $null   # this won't affect the real server value

    return $site
}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName REMOTEPC -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
```

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem as you. I was in an iteration trying to create 16 sites. First one was being created and had same exception... exiting from iteration and leaving me with only one site created. I didn't fix it, but as a **workaround** I added

> | out-null

at the end of the line. This suppresed output so exception was ignored and my iteration was happily continuing.

Something like:

```
invoke-command -computername REMOTEPC -scriptblock { import-module WebAdministration; new-item "$env:systemdrive\inetpub\testsite" -type directory; New-WebSite -Name TestSite -Port 81 -PhysicalPath "$env:systemdrive\inetpub\testsite" | out-null}
```

(Notice that | out-null at the end of the code snippet)